# How do i scaffold DbContext with plural DbSet property names in as.net core EFCore 3?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How do i scaffold `DbContext` with plural `DbSet` property names in **asp.net core EFCore** 3 ? and where they exist more than one capital letters in a table name **(e.g. AutoShipment)** it generates all except the first letters lowercase **(e.g. Autoshipment.cs)**

Comment: Specify the -UseDatabaseNames https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding#preserving-names

Comment: Thank You so much @krlosmederos. It worked great for the 2nd Problem..i.e retaining tables name as it is in DB. But the Pluralizing still remains unresolved. I tried with 'Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer' but seems like it doesn't support EF 3 anymore!

Comment: After scaffolding you should refactor the code to pluralize the classes.I don't know another way to do it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, I recommend you use the following extension [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools)

Among its features is generating code from an existing database and you can configure how to do reverse engineering.

[More details here](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution @krlosmederos. **Geco** - [link](https://github.com/iQuarc/Geco/wiki) (https://github.com/iQuarc/Geco/wiki)  resolved both of the issue (Pluralizing Database Tables Name and Table Name Convention to Pascal Case)

Comment: [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) is great, but you have to compromise with the Naming Convention.    Singularize/Pluralize and also disable the EF Core urge to "properly" Camelize/Pascalize names.
Changes in the DB occur quite often, so that reverse engineering will happen over and over again. Therefore it does not make sense to adjust the existing code base manually each time again.

Answer (score 0):

**Lifesaver, easiest way:**

Install this NUGET package inside the dbContext project:
[Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer)
and here is his source code:
https://github.com/bricelam/EFCore.Pluralizer

It works fine with .net core 3.1, (you don't need it for.net 5 or higher)